# function that can differ between two different events (sns and emr) in python in lambda function

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda, amazon-emr, amazon-sns

I have a lambda function that is triggered by both an sns event and emr event. The events look different and do not share any key:value pairs .my current way keeps giving me a KeyError.

Ideally, i want this lambda function to receive  either sns or emr event. Then based on what type of event it does one thing or another. I don't want to split this into two different lambda functions as it shares all of the same code minus a couple small things.

emr event:

```
  "version": "0",
  "id": "foo",
  "detail-type": "EMR Step Status Change",
  "source": "aws.emr",
  "resources": [],
  "detail": {
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "actionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
    "stepId": "s-ZYXWVUTSRQPON",
    "clusterId": "j-123456789ABCD",
    "state": "FAILED",
    "message": "foo."
  }
}
```

sns event

```
  "Records": [
    {
      "EventSource": "aws:sns",
      "EventVersion": "1.0",
      "EventSubscriptionArn": "foo",
      "Sns": {
        "Type": "Notification",
        "MessageId": "foo",
        "MessageAttributes": {
          "Metadata": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "{\"param1\": \"1\", \"parma2\": \"2\"}"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried:

```
    if "Sns" in event["Records"][0]:
        print("do that")
    elif "aws.emr" in event["Source"][0]:
        print("do this")
```

Answer (score 0):

If an EMR event comes, then your function first checks `event["Records"][0]`. Since `Records` is not a key in the event dictionary, you will get a key error. The following code snippet should satisfy your need.

```
records = event.get("Records")
if (records is not None) and ("Sns" in records[0]):
    print("do that")
else:
    print("do this")
```

You can use try catch too.

```
try:
    if "Sns" in event["Records"][0]:
        print("do that")
except KeyError:
    if "aws.emr" in event["Source"][0]:
        print("do this")
    else:
        raise
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I'm going to end up throwing this in a try/except  on the off chance another event makes it way there(shouldn't happen but covering bases). Is there a way to tweak your answer?  Again Thanks!

Comment: @danvers18 I have added the try/except approach.

Comment: i thought this code snipped with the try/catch and the emr part works but the sns event keeps erring out with a [ERROR] KeyError: 'source' and the lambda function stops at the error